# Unable to install Symfony4

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I've been trying to install Symfony version 4 for a few days now, by running the command in the official installation guide :

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my-project or composer create-project symfony/skeleton my-project
```

Here's what I get (installation of v3.4 instead of 4) :

[image]

Here's my version of php :

[image]

Comment: And what is wrong? And btw `Symfony 4.0 requires PHP 7.1.3 or higher`

Comment: run again with composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my-project -vv and give me the output

Answer (score 1):

check this link:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/requirements.html

Symfony 4.0 requires PHP 7.1.3 or higher to run, in addition to other minor requirements.

You can cd into your project and run

```
composer require requirements-checker --dev
```

After that, you need to copy the two files php-requirements-checker.php and my-requirements.php into your php application An other method will be to use composer to get the last stable release. Go to the composer section to do it.

If it helps here is the packiagist link: https://packagist.org/packages/nmalservet/php-requirements-checker

Finally, don't forget to increase verbosity (vv)

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my-project -vv
```

Comment: OP's using symfony 3.4 components, that require php `^7.0.8`

Comment: But the OP has indicated they want to install SF4.  It's composer that is falling back to 3.4.  Of course the OP never did say what the problem was in the first place and it looks to be a drive by question anyways.